# Transfer eclipse and android SDK to new Computer

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an good eclipse and ADT on it and everything is good. but i have to transfer it to my new computer and I m worry about reinstalling google and eclipse plugins again.

please help me to find a way for offline transfer of all my eclipse, plugins, android sdk and android emulator

Comment: Same operating system and Java architecture (i.e. 32/64 bit)?

Comment: yes. windows 7 64. issue is my slow internet connection (everything is 32 bit applications on 64 windows)

Answer (score 1):

for using in the same architecture and also the same OS, simply copy eclipse and sdk folders. if you want your emulators too, in linux, copy ~/.android folder too.

Comment: after this work, the android plugins in eclipse didnt work. i test it on a VM

Comment: Did you copy the workspace also? Are the paths the same? Did it help to set the path to the SDK or is the plugin itself not available?